# Separate string from dat file

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have few .dat files which data look like this.

```
˙˙˙Pb16.5 Nw2          ..00-R0634  317.                    PRESSURE            400.0     CMH2O 1750.0    CMH2O 1750.0    CMH2O 400.0     CMH2O TEMPERATURE         -20.00    °C    100.00    °C    100.00    °C    -20.00    °C    2:Spec.cond.        0.00      mS/cm 120.00    mS/cm 120.00    mS/cm 0.00      mS/cm 00 00:60:00 0T   00:00:15 29/01/14  00:00:14 30/01/14~**5  ~*–5  ‡*>4  *o3  –*î2  ˇ*z2  ¬*W2
```

I need to separate this line into two strings. First string will have:

```
˙˙˙Pb16.5 Nw2          ..00-R0634  317.                    PRESSURE            400.0     CMH2O 1750.0    CMH2O 1750.0    CMH2O 400.0     CMH2O TEMPERATURE         -20.00    °C    100.00    °C    100.00    °C    -20.00    °C    2:Spec.cond.        0.00      mS/cm 120.00    mS/cm 120.00    mS/cm 0.00      mS/cm 00 00:60:00 0T   00:00:15 29/01/14  00:00:14 30/01/14
```

and secound:

```
~**5  ~*–5  ‡*>4  *o3  –*î2  ˇ*z2  ¬*W2
```

Problem is next: I mention on top of this question that I have few .dat files, and their data is not indetical. I can easily separate with ~ char in this example, but problem is that files data is not same. In some other files after that last date are some other characters like `s*ő4  x*^5` or `ÝM};ô`. I cant separate by definite char. Maybe I could separate by bytes because I know number of bytes, its first 347 bytes, but I dont know how.

```
string url = @"E:Data.dat";
using (Stream stream = File.Open(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string str = sr.ReadToEnd(); // or sr.ReadBlock();
               //code to separate string after last date
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create char array and give him a value. Then I create int readBytes and give him to readBlock from stream reader(sr) where is range 500, starst from first char and read first 59 chars .

```
 using (Stream stream = File.Open(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[500];
                    int readBytes = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, 59);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how consistent the input files are, but it seems that the values you want to extract start with a ~. The first ~ in line, so for each line you could fetch the index of the ~ character and read the string from there :

```
    string url = @"E:Data.dat";
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,     FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
             string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
             var characterIndex = str.IndexOf('~');
             if (characterIndex >= 0)
             {
                var result = str.SubString(characterIndex, str.Length - characterIndex);
                // Work from here
             }
        }
    }
```